# "Invalid JWT Signature." with meteor-google-oauth-jwt

Tags: authentication, meteor, oauth, jwt

I am trying to submit a sitemap.xml programmatically, following instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/sitemaps/submit#auth

I do:

```
// Just call this once to set JWT
HTTPJWT.setJWTOptions({
    email : "[ client ID up to the first dot ]@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    key : Assets.getText("key.pem"), // Get key file from assets
    scopes : [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters"
    ],
});

var submitUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.spoticle.com/sitemaps/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.spoticle.com%2Fsitemap.xml";
var result = HTTPJWT.get(submitUrl);
```

... and here is the result:

Error: failed [400] { "error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "Invalid JWT Signature." }

I can, however, generate a JWT by doing:

```
var jwt = GoogleOAuthJWT.encodeJWT({
    email : "[ client ID up to the first dot ]@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    key : Assets.getText("key.pem"), // Get key file from assets
    scopes : [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters"
    ]
});
```

... but I don't know how to verify that this token is valid.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you read/did all of those steps? https://github.com/extrabacon/google-oauth-jwt#creating-a-service-account-using-the-google-developers-console

Comment: Yep.  Been there, done that.  Anyway, it turns out what I need is actually called a "ping"... not to resubmit the sitemap.xml.  This is far simpler, as it does not require any auth.